# SQL Calculations over tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

There are 2 tables, there is an expected result, the result is to have the total cost of each engagement calculated, there are multiple tests taken during each engagement, each test ranges in cost (all set values), the expected result must be in terms of `EngagementId, EngagementCost`

The 2 tables, with there respective fields

```
 - EngagementTest (EngagementId, TestId)
 - Test (TestId, TestCost)
```

[image]

How would one go calculating the cost of each engagement.

This is as far as i managed to get

```
   SELECT EngagementId, COUNT(TESTId)
   FROM EngagementTest
   GROUP BY EngagementId;
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free homework service.

Comment: I used the COUNT function, but soon realised that i couldnt complete the task using that, i moved things around and still was unable to figure out what to do, there is a whole other task but this is the certain bit that i didn't understand

Comment: Please post what you tried

Comment: Read up on joins: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/  you need to join engagementTest to Test on the TestID's this join will then put the testCost next to each testID and allow you to sum and group by engagementID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a `SUM` of the TestCost column rather than a `COUNT`. `COUNT` just tells you the number of rows. `SUM` adds up the values within the rows and gives you a total. Also your existing query doesn't actually use the table that contains the cost data. You can `INNER JOIN` the two tables via `TestId` and then `GROUP BY` the EngagementId so you get the sum of each engagement.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  ET.EngagementId, 
  SUM(T.TestCost)
FROM
  EngagementTest ET
  INNER JOIN Test T
    ON T.TestId = ET.TestId
GROUP BY
  ET.EngagementId
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using below query.

```
SELECT i.EngagementId, SUM(TestCost)
FROM EngagementTest  i
INNER JOIN Test  t
ON e.TestId = t.TestId
GROUP BY i.EngagementId
```

Comment: the query is correct but a better quality answer would explain the code for the OP and future readers - especially since OP is clearly a beginner in SQL. Otherwise it's not necessarily clear what the code does or which parts are important.